# HOW to SELECT data basing on both a period of date and a period of time in clickhouse

Tags: sql, datetime, time-series, clickhouse, dolphindb

I want to filter some data by both `yyyymmdd`(date) and `hhmmss`(time), but clickhouse don't support `time` type. So I choose `datetime` to combine them. But how to do such things:

This is code of `dolphindb`(which supports `second` type to represent `hhmmss`.

```
select avg(ofr + bid) / 2.0 as avg_price
from taq
where
    date between 2007.08.05 : 2007.08.07,
    time between 09:30:00 : 16:00:00
group by symbol, date
```

This is code of `clickhouse`, but a logical problematic code.

```sql
SELECT avg(ofr + bid) / 2.0 AS avg_price
FROM taq
WHERE
    time BETWEEN '2007-08-05 09:30:00' AND '2007-08-07 16:00:00'
GROUP BY symbol, toYYYYMMDD(time)
;
```

how to express it in sql just like the `dolphindb` code?

Answer (score 4):

Assume that you just want to average the trading price in normal trading hours, excluding after hour trading, then a possible solution:

```
SELECT avg(ofr + bid) / 2.0 AS avg_price
FROM taq
WHERE
    toYYYYMMDD(time) BETWEEN 20070805 AND 20070807 AND
    toYYYYMMDDhhmmss(time)%1000000 BETWEEN 93000 and 160000
GROUP BY symbol, toYYYYMMDD(time)
```

This filters the **taq** table within specified date and time.